# Is it possible to implement the state design pattern in C++ without dynamic polymorphism?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, polymorphism, static-polymorphism

Let's say I have following C++ code

```
class ControlAlgorithm {

public:
    virtual void update() = 0;
    virtual void enable() = 0;
    virtual void disable() = 0;
};

class Algorithm_A : public ControlAlgorithm {

public:
    void update();
    void enable();
    void disable();
};

class Algorithm_B : public ControlAlgorithm {

public:
    void update();
    void enable();
    void disable();
};

Algorithm_A algorithm_A;
Algorithm_B algorithm_B;
ControlAlgorithm *algorithm;
```

Lets's say I would like to switch between the `algorithm_A` and `algorithm_B` during run-time based on some external events (basically I am going to implement the state design pattern). So the `algorithm` pointer points either to the `algorithm_A` or `algorithm_B` object. My question is whether there is any method how to achieve the ability to dynamic switch between the algorithms during run-time without the virtual methods in the
common interface e.g. the curiously recurring template pattern?

Comment: Why do you need that? It may be easier to answer when we know the need for this. For example, you could have function maps, but that's just dynamic polymorphism with extra steps. Is there just 2 states to choose from? `switch` might not be too bad of an option.

Comment: Yes don't use the state pattern. I always find it too verbose, leads to too many classes and its hard to keep track of the actual behavior. At it base an FSM is a functional problem, and I usually tackle it as in a table based approach, In this state, with this trigger, call that response function and move to the next state. And for small machines a switch case is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Something like below, for example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct control_algorithm {
    const std::function<void()> update;
    const std::function<void()> enable;
    const std::function<void()> edit;
};

control_algorithm make_algorithm_A() {
    return {
        []() { std::cout << "update A\n"; },
        []() { std::cout << "enable A\n"; },
        []() { std::cout << "edit A\n"; },
    };
}

control_algorithm make_algorithm_B() {
    return {
        []() { std::cout << "update B\n"; },
        []() { std::cout << "enable B\n"; },
        []() { std::cout << "edit B\n"; },
    };
}

int main()
{
    auto algorithm_A = make_algorithm_A();
    auto algorithm_B = make_algorithm_B();
    auto control = algorithm_A;
    //auto control = algorithm_B;
}
```

Comment: Now there's dynamic polymorphism hidden inside `std::function`

Comment: whether that matters depends on why the OP is asking the question but in any case you could do the same thing with function pointers.